# Integrability Reformulation Proof

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification

Suppose you had a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ that is defined by $f(x) = -\sqrt{2}$ if $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, and $6.9$ if $x\not\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Using the Integrability Reformulation definition, how would I prove its not integrable on the closed interval $[-1,1]$?

---

Could somebody help me out, I am not really sure how this definition works, their is no section in my book with this definition, just lecture stuff, which I didn't understand.

**My understanding:**

We want to show there exists some $\epsilon >0$, for all $p\in [-1,1]$ such that $U(f,p) -L(f,p)$ must be greater than or equal to $\epsilon$. I am not sure how to pick this $\epsilon$. I understand I should by using infimum's and supremum's.

Comment: Fix a partition.  What is the upper sum?  What is the lower sum?  You will use that over any nonempty interval of real numbers there exist both rational and irrational numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Choose $\epsilon = 10$, and let $P = \{-1=x_0, x_1, x_2, ...x_{n-1},x_n = 1\}$ be **any** partition of $[-1,1]$, then calculate $U(f,P) = 6.9(x_1-(-1)) + 6.9(x_2-x_1)+\cdots+ 6.9(1-x_{n-1}) = 6.9(2) = 13.8$, and $L(f,P) = -2\sqrt{2}$. Thus $U(f,P) - L(f,P) = 13.8 + 2\sqrt{2} > 10 = \epsilon$, proving $f$ not integrable.